# How to check if the input is within the first column of the matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have created a matrix called `rix`.

```
rix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6][7,8,9]]
```

And as an input I have variable `put` which is a single list of length `2` which represents the position of the matrix. The part that I'm struggling in, is how do I  check that the variable put represents one of the positions in the first column?

Answer (score 0):

Design your function to be generic; it should take the argument `row_n` (*row number*) that represents which row you want to check its bounds. Check if the `row_n` exists in your `rix`'s list. Then, do a comparison between your `put`'s second element (*that represents the expected row length*) with the *original* `row_n` length in the `rix` list.

According to your case, you should compare if the `put`'s second element is less than or equal to the `rix`'s `row_n` length and then return your booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You use `len(rix)` to evaluate the number of rows 
and `len(rix[0])` to evaluate the number of columns your matrix has

so

```
if len(rix) <= put[0]:
    return false
elif len(rix[0]) <= put[1]:
    return false
else:
    return true
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to consider negative indices.

```
def in_first_col(put, list2D):
    row_idx, col_idx = put

    # return False if we can't get the row
    try:
       row = list2D[row_idx]
    except IndexError:
       return False

    # return False if row is empty
    # return False if col_idx does not refer to first element of row
    return row and (col_idx == 0 or col_idx == -len(row))
```

Demo:

```
>>> rix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> in_first_col([1,1], rix)
>>> False
>>> in_first_col([2,0], rix)
>>> True
>>> in_first_col([5,0], rix)
>>> False
>>> in_first_col([-2,-3], rix)
>>> True
```

Comment: Don't you think that posting code while showing no attempt from the OP is against the main use of SO?